# Executor tasks for parallelizing a method

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice, callable

So I am trying to delete n files from the disk which are listed in listDir  and thereby I divided the listDir in 4 parts and let it to be deleted in parallel from the disk. The intention here is to do it in parallel so as to make it fast rather than sequential. deleteObject(x,credential,token) can be assumed as an API which finally deletes an object from the disk and is an atomic operation. It returns true on successful delete and false otherwise

I have few question here

1. So as I have 4 parallel method which I am executing though invokeAll
   and there are 4 threads declared by Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
   would there always be 1 thread be assigned to 1 method?
2. Do I need to synchronize and use volatile for iterator 'i' in the for loop of parallelDeleteOperation() method. The reason I am asking this is supposing if 1st thread has not completed its task (deleting listDir1 and the for loop has not completed) and supposing in midway it got context switch and 2nd thread starts executing the same task(deleting listDir1). Just wondering if 2nd thread can get IndexOutOfBound exception in this case.
3. Is there any advantage of dividing list in 4 parts and executing this rather than having multiple threads executing delete operation on a very big list.
4. If one of the operation of ExecutorService returns false then on the whole deleteMain() API would return false

   ```
    private boolean deleteMain(String parent, List<Structure>
       listDir, String place, String node, Sequence<String>
                                  groups, String Uid) throws IOException {

   int noCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
   List<List<Integer>> splittedList = splitList(listDir, noCores);

   System.out.println(splittedList.size());

   System.out.println("NoOfCores" + noCores);
   Set<Callable<Boolean>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<Boolean>>();
   for (int i = 0; i < splittedList.size(); i++) {
       List<Integer> l = splittedList.get(i);
       callables.add(new Callable<Boolean>() {
           @Override
           public Boolean call() throws Exception {

               return parallelDeleteOperation(parent, listDir, place, node, groups Uid);
           }
       });
   }

   ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noCores);

   try {
       List<Future<Boolean>> futures = service.invokeAll(callables);


       for (Future<Boolean> future : futures) {
           if (future.get() != true)
               return future.get();
       }
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ExecutionException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   service.shutdown();
   return true;
   }

   private Boolean parallelDeleteOperation(String parent, List<Structure>
       listDir, String place, String node, Sequence<String>
                                               groups, String Uid) throws IOException {
   for (int i = 0; i < listDir.size(); i++) {
       final String name = listDir.get(i).filename;

       final String filePath = "/" + (parent.isEmpty() ? "" : (parent +
               "/")) + name;
       final DeleteMessage message = new DeleteMessage(name, place, node
               filePath);
       final boolean Status = delete(message, groups, Uid, place);
       if (Status != true)
           return Status;
   }
   return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: Replace the whole thing with `listDir.parallelStream().forEach(this::deleteObject);`.

Comment: have modified the deleteObject code a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. So as I have 4 parallel method which I am executing though invokeAll and there are 4 threads declared by Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4) would there always be 1 thread be assigned to 1 method?

Normally it's right if the tasks amount is equal to the threads in the pool but there is no guarantee. It depends pretty much on the tasks in the pool.

```
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4).invokeAll(IntStream.range(0, 8).mapToObj(i -> (Callable<Integer>) () -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + i);
            return 0;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

If there are more tasks in the pool, as above, the output can be as follows. There is no obvious predictable rule to process the tasks:

```
pool-1-thread-1: 0
pool-1-thread-2: 1
pool-1-thread-3: 2
pool-1-thread-1: 4
pool-1-thread-1: 5
pool-1-thread-1: 6
pool-1-thread-1: 7
pool-1-thread-4: 3
```

> 2. Do I need to synchronize and use volatile for iterator 'i' in the for loop of parallelDeleteOperation() method.

No, you need not. You've already splitted up your original list into separate *four lists*.

In your code:

> final List listDir1 = listDir.subList(0, listDir.size() / 4);

As for your No.3 question:

> 3. Is there any advantage of dividing list in 4 parts and executing this rather than having multiple threads executing delete operation on a very big list.

You'd better have some tests under realistic conditions. Which is too complicated to just say it's better or not.

When you are deleting *on a big list*, the race condition could be more severe than splitting up the list beforehand, which might be extra overhead.

Besides, even without any **parallelism**, its performance could be not bad. And when it comes to **multi-user** system the parallelized version can be even worse than the sequential one due to thread context switching overhead.

You have to test them and the test assistant code can be:

```
    Long start = 0L;
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1_000; ++i) {
        start = System.nanoTime();
        // your method to be tested;
        list.add(System.nanoTime() - start);
    }
    System.out.println("Time cost summary: " + list.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingLong(Long::valueOf)));
```

> 4. If one of the operation of ExecutorService returns false then on the whole deleteMain() API would return false

I'd like to refactor your code as this making it cleaner and also meet your last requirement (No.4):

```
// using the core as the count;
// since your task is CPU-bound, we can directly use parallelStream;
private static void testThreadPool(List<Integer> listDir) {
    // if one of the tasks failed, you got isFailed == true;
    boolean isFailed = splitList(listDir, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()).stream()
            .parallel().map(YourClass::parallelDeleteOperation).anyMatch(ret -> ret == false); // if any is false, it gives you false
}


// split up the list into "count" lists;
private static <T> List<List<T>> splitList(List<T> list, int count) {
    List<List<T>> listList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0, blockSize = list.size() / count; i < count; ++i) {
        listList.add(list.subList(i * blockSize, Math.min((i+1) * blockSize, list.size()));
    }
    return listList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hearen , I get it and it make sense to me. I am thinking of a way if I can make deleteObject(x,credential,token) executed in a parallel way .... So basically deleteObject(x,credential,token) is an API which deletes the file from the disk and is an atomic operation ...... The listDir which is my main list has the names of the files which are to be deleted. Is there someway to do it without dividing the list in parts. So basically I am looking for to read the listDir once (without splitting) and call this deleteObject(x,credential,token) parallel. I am just out of options here.

Comment: `listDir.stream().parallel().map(ClassName::deleteMethod).anyMatch(ret -> ret==false)` should just do the whole trick.

Comment: Is there any other advantage of using a direct stream().parallel() operation rather than using split option as you have suggested based on no of cores. I read somewhere online that even parallel operation would split the stream based on CPU cores and execute the operation. So basically now I have my main list split on the basis of no of cores using availableProcessors() and then use executors invoke all to execute it all with FixedThreadPool as number of Cpu Cores.

Comment: @vippu It’s using a default forkJoinPool which will be shared by the program. But for for overall performance, it should be better than your own scheduling method by splitting up the big list.

Comment: Thanks a lot and i understood the difference now. So basically I spent my whole day converting my above program to use a parallel stream. I have updated the actual code above how it looks like now but finding hard to get it converted in streams. I am still learning how to write streams but stuck on this program for a very long time and ending up in errors. :(

Comment: For sure,  A lot of my doubts got cleared with your answer. I am still a new developer and new to stackoverflow. Seems like me upvoting would not be displayed as public but yes I have given a positive checkmark to your answer

Comment: Do you recommend some good and useful videos I can see about stream API in java 8. I am trying to make my above code work with stream().parallel() operation but no luck till now

Comment: this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/tag/java-streams/ and this project: https://github.com/Hearen/JavaSe8Solutions

Comment: As I read about parallel streams, seems like they take advantage of the main thread along with the threads from the ForkjoinCommonpool(). Now these threads from ForkJoinCommonPool can be shared among resources. Now in case of a multi requests at a single time -> would there always be 1 dedicated main thread to do a particular request and the threads in the CommonPool would be shared? What happens incase I have a dedicated pool of threads rather than common pool. Supposing a pool of 4 threads and there are 10 requests to process. Wld my 6 requests be cancelled if I don't have a req que.

Comment: @vippu A nice question, but I really think you should start a new question to elaborate it further since it’s different from the current one :)

Comment: Sure. Thanks wld do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any advantage to split the list in 4 sublists: as soon a a thread terminates its list, it will be idle. If you submit a task for each element in the input list, all four threads will be active until the queue is empty.

UPDATE:
as someone noted, you can use a `parallelStream`, it's simpler and probably faster; but if you want to keep the `ExecutorService`, you can do something like that:

```
    int noCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    List<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noCores);
    try {
        for (Structure s: listDir) {
            String name = s.filename;
            String filePath = "/" + (parent.isEmpty() ? "" : (parent
                + "/")) + name;
            Future<Boolean> result = service.submit(()-> {
                final DeleteMessage message = new DeleteMessage(
                        name, place, node, filePath);
                return delete(message, groups, Uid, place);
            });
            futures.add(result);
        }
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: I agree, but that would require synchronizing the list read operation else 4 threads reading from the list would not be in order?

Comment: @vippu no, actually it would not: you don't need to use the list from within the tasks

Comment: Thanks,  I up-voted your response but seems like it wont be displayed.